# Sed, parse out between two lines, but only print a limited lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

My details are lengthy, yet simple :)
I have a file like following:

```
Iteration 1
blah blah
.
.
.
blah blah
pattern 1 
detail 1
detail 2
blah blah
.
.
.
blah blah
Iteration 2
.
.
.
Iteration 10
blah blah
.
.
.
blah blah
pattern 1 
detail 1
detail 2
blah blah
.
.
.
blah blah
```

(Some iterations do not have `pattern 1`). In this example only iteration 1 and iteration 10 contain the pattern.
There is always 2 detail lines after my pattern (detail 1 and detail 2) in which I am interested.

What I need is to parse out the iteration number, pattern and details (if that specific iteration contains the pattern) something like this:

```
Iteration 1
pattern 1
detail 1
detail 2
Iteration 10
pattern 1
...
```

What I did is :

```
 sed -n '/Iteration/H;/pattern 1/{N;N;x;G;p}' file
```

The problem:

My output is something like

```
Iteration 1
pattern 1
detail 1
detail 2
pattern 1
detail 1
detail 2
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
```

**It prints out my pattern and details 2 times.
It also prints out all of the iterations ( I want only the number of iterations being parsed out which include pattern).**

Comment: Q: Why not pipe sed to grep (or vice versa, dependent on which is more selective)?  For example: `sed -n SOMETHING file|grep SOMETHING ELSE`.

Comment: Since it is line-oriented in nature, sed is always the wrong choice for anything involving multiple lines. Now, edit your question to provide TESTABLE input and output and an explanation of the mapping. Your expected output shows an `Iteration 10` that's not in your input and it's not clear, for example, if there's always exactly 2 "detail" lines after a "pattern" line or if they always start with the word "detail" or.... And get rid of the text "something like" - show us specifically what it IS you want, not something like it.

Comment: @FoggyDay, as far as I know `grep` doesn't work between lines unless, I use `-P`, and I am not familiar with `perl regexp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
#                  v-- here
sed -n '/Iteration/h;/pattern 1/{N;N;x;G;p}' file
```

`H` appends the current line to the hold buffer, `h` replaces the hold buffer with it. You want the latter, or you'll have a lot of cruft assembled in later matching blocks -- which is then printed.

Answer (score 1):

If your file has no blank lines, use sed to preprocess by breaking the file up into records that are separated by blank lines:

```
sed '/Iteration/i\
\
' input | awk '/pattern/' RS=
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `RS="(^|\n)Iteration"` with GNU awk.

Comment: It contains lots of blank lines actually.